# Catching all common types of redirection, header, meta, JavaScript, etc

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, http-headers, http-redirect

I'm in need of a function that tests a URL if it is redirected by whatever means.

So far, I have used cURL to catch header redirects, but there are obviously more ways to achieve a redirect.

Eg.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/somewhere/on/this/server" />
```

or JS scripts

```
window.location = 'http://melbourne.ag';
```

etc.

I was wondering if anybody has a solution that covers them all. I'll keep working on mine and will post the result here.

Also, a quick way of parsing

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"...
```

in PHP anyone?

I thought this would be included in PHP's native get_meta_tags() ... but I thought wrong :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Halfway there, I'll add the JS checks when I wrote them...

```
 function checkRedirect($url){
    // returns the redirected URL or the original
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);

    $out = str_replace("\r", "", $out);

    $headers_end = strpos($out, "\n\n");
    if( $headers_end !== false ) { 
        $out = substr($out, 0, $headers_end);
    }   

    $headers = explode("\n", $out);
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if(strtolower(substr($header, 0, 10)) == "location: " ) { 
            $target = substr($header, 10);
            return $target;
        }   
    }   

     return $url;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done for markup languages (any simple markup parser will do), but it cannot be done in general for programming languages like JavaScript.

Redirection in a program in a Web document is equivalent to halting that program. You are asking for a program that is able to tell whether another, *arbitrary* program will halt. This is known in computer science as the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), the first undecidable problem.

That is, you will only be able to tell *correctly* for a *subset* of resources whether redirection will occur.

Comment: They, too, (can) only catch a *subset*.

Comment: How does Google then end up indexing a page - at the end of a redirection chain? They must read out all redirections somehow?

Comment: They consider several levels of *HTTP* redirection. STFW.

Comment: "STFW"? LOL. Basically, what you're saying is: "I don't know. Look for it yourself."

Comment: No, I am basically saying “type ‘google redirection’ into the Google search field and look at the first hits”. Google *explains* itself on the Web. If you cannot be bothered to do *some* research, why should I hand mine to you? It is *your* problem, not mine.

Comment: a) I have done "some" research - see the question.
b) If you "can't be bothered to hand over yours" what are you doing on this site and why did you bother to "answer" my questions (regardless of how little practical use it contains) in the first place?